# Duplicates in "n × hamming weight of n" sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory, binary

### Background

The sequence in the title is [A245788](https://oeis.org/A245788) "n times the number of 1's in the binary expansion of n" ("times" here means multiplication), which starts like this:

```
1,   2,   6,   4,   10,  12,  21,  8,   18,  20,
33,  24,  39,  42,  60,  16,  34,  36,  57,  40,
63,  66,  92,  48,  75,  78,  108, 84,  116, 120,
155, 32,  66,  68,  105, 72,  111, 114, 156, 80,
123, 126, 172, 132, 180, 184, 235, 96,  147, 150,
204, 156, 212, 216, 275, 168, 228, 232, 295, 240, ...
```

Though it is not immediately obvious, this sequence has some duplicates (same number appearing at least twice). The first duplicate appears at \$a(22) = a(33) = 66\$. The next ones are \$a(39) = a(52) = 156\$, and \$a(44) = a(66) = 132\$. Note that the duplicates do not appear in ascending order.

It is easy to prove that there exist infinitely many duplicates in this sequence, and I suspect that there exist infinitely many \$k\$-plicates (the numbers that appear at least \$k\$ times in the sequence) as well. For the record, the first triplicate entry is \$a(1236) = a(1545) = a(2060) = 6180\$.

### Challenge

Produce the sequence of **unique** duplicates in A245788, **in ascending order**. For example, 156 should appear after 132, and 6180 should appear only once in the sequence. The following is the list of all 124 terms under 10000, generated using [this Python program](https://tio.run/##NY/BDoIwEETv/YpJPNAaMBJvRL34GcQDQtFNoG1KSTDGb8ct4J66u29npu4dXtac5rn1tkdtu07XgawZQL2zPuBmRxO0Fw3VuODzFc3o@FHeRWs9CGTgK/PUMk/zI5cqBFARI4Q9HmQkqUMdRWSSJ4qX1MY937FkhIEdnCcGeFBWdE9BKZIsY6fsmqRMqwXj/lA5p00j15HuBl1gu4qOYtUZOLhu5KCDnBBjTosdB2fvCWesSZUSf@ftl5IZpeb5Bw):

```
66,   132,  156,  228,  264,  300,  312,  420,  435,  456,
528,  588,  600,  624,  804,  840,  870,  912,  1056, 1100,
1164, 1176, 1200, 1220, 1248, 1545, 1572, 1608, 1635, 1680,
1740, 1824, 2050, 2100, 2112, 2196, 2200, 2244, 2316, 2328,
2340, 2352, 2400, 2440, 2496, 2580, 2628, 2820, 3090, 3108,
3140, 3144, 3216, 3270, 3325, 3360, 3480, 3535, 3648, 3690,
4025, 4098, 4100, 4200, 4224, 4260, 4392, 4400, 4488, 4620,
4632, 4656, 4680, 4704, 4800, 4880, 4914, 4992, 5160, 5256,
5640, 5880, 6125, 6180, 6195, 6216, 6280, 6288, 6432, 6510,
6540, 6650, 6660, 6720, 6960, 7070, 7296, 7380, 7608, 8040,
8050, 8196, 8200, 8220, 8292, 8400, 8448, 8490, 8520, 8580,
8784, 8800, 8976, 9228, 9240, 9264, 9312, 9360, 9408, 9600,
9732, 9760, 9828, 9984
```

Default I/O methods for [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) are allowed:

- Take no input, and output the terms infinitely.
- Take \$n\$ as input, and output the \$n\$-th term (0- or 1-indexed).
- Take \$n\$ as input, and output the first \$n\$ terms.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 13):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>72 71 70</s>  69 bytes

A full program that prints the sequence forever.

```javascript
for(n=1;c=2;c||print(n))for(d=++n;d--;)c>>=n==(h=n=>n&&h(n&n-1)+d)(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCsAgDADA30iCONipIPEvEhHtkIoVJ/@etssNd6WVHh6tT7dO1XIPEPKB6Qi8dx9NJgji/5mslZCdC8gxkhBB/YxiTAUx4jzajJBRC6C@)

#### Commented

```javascript
for(                   // infinite outer loop:
  n = 1;               //   start with n = 1
  c = 2;               //   before each iteration: initialize c to 2
  c || print(n)        //   after each iteration: print n if c = 0
)                      //
  for(                 //   inner loop:
    d = ++n;           //     increment n and start with d = n
    d--;               //     stop when d = 0 / decrement d
  )                    //
    c >>=              //     right-shift d by 1 position if ...
      n == (           //       ... n is equal to ...
        h = n =>       //       ... the result of the recursive function h
          n &&         //       which adds d as many times as there are
          h(n & n - 1) //       bits set in d, using n & n - 1 to clear
          + d          //       the least significant bit at each iteration
      )(d)             //
```

#### Note

We decrement \$d\$ right away in the inner loop, which means that we never consider the case where the divisor of \$n\$ is \$n\$ itself. But that would only work if there's a single 1 in the binary representation of \$n\$, which means that \$n\$ is a power of \$2\$ and all its divisors have a single 1 in their binary representation as well. Therefore, \$n=1\times n\$ is the only possible solution and \$n\$ does not belong to the sequence.

Comment: 66: `for(d=o=[];;o[d]&&print(d))o[p=(h=n=>n&&h(n&n-1)+d)(++d)]=o[p]+1|0`

Comment: @tsh Nice. I think this is different enough to be posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
×BS)ċ>1µ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdKdgzSPddoaHtir//29oAAA)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

### Explanation

```
×BS)ċ>1µ#  Main Link
        #  nfind; find first (read from stdin) numbers such that
     >1    there is more than one
    ċ      occurrence of the original number in the list of
   )       each number from 1 to N
×BS        multiplied by its hamming weight
```

Note that `×BS` doesn't actually chain as `× (B S)`. In other words, this isn't *actually* multiplying each number by its hamming weight. However, by distribution of multiplication over addition, instead of doing \$a\times(b_1+b_2+\dots+b_n)\$, it's actually doing \$ab_1+ab_2+\dots+ab_n\$ because `×` vectorizes, and those happen to be literally the same thing. It chains as `(× B) S`, but that ends up giving the same result.

Comment: Save one replacing `Ɗ€` with `)` [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdKdgzSPddoaHtir//29oAAA).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Totally forgot that existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Scala, <s>144</s> 135 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to Kirill L.!

```scala
n=>Stream.from(1).scanLeft(0::Nil)((s,x)=>x*Integer.bitCount(x)::s).collect{case h::t if t toSet h=>h}.distinct.take(n*2).sorted take n
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OmFSOXakSLmRspjSApwo7Q)

Pretty naive solution. Returns the first n elements.

```scala
n =>  //How many elements you want
Stream.from(1)  //Infinite list of natural numbers
.scanLeft(0::Nil) //Scan left, collecting prefixes of hamming number sequence (reversed)
((s,x) =>    //s is the previous sequence, x is a natural number
  x * Integer.bitCount(x)  //Find the next hamming number
    ::s)   //Prepend to s
.collect{  //Keep the ones that work with this PartialFunction:
  case h::t  //A prefix with hamming number h at the start and initial piece t
    if t toSet h =>  //If h is a duplicate
    h        //Keep h
}.distinct  //Uniquify
.take(n*2)  //Take the first 2n elements
.sorted    //Sort them
take n    //Take the first n elements
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using [Java interop for bitCount](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mks6mMA8Q4Gy1H0lSijFhg). I had to use fully qualified class name to make it work, but I don't know Scala, so maybe it can be shortened somehow.

Comment: @KirillL. Thanks! I made it work with `Integer`, which is imported by default, although `java.lang.Long` clashes with `scala.Long`

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
.f<1lfq*TsjT2ZS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/NxjAnrVArpDgrxCgq@P9/YwA)

Outputs the first \$n\$ elements of the sequence.

Explanation:

```
.f<1lfq*TsjT2ZS   | Full program
.f<1lfq*TsjT2ZSZQ | with implicit variables
------------------+--------------------------------------------------
.f              Q | first Q (input) numbers Z starting at 1 such that
    lf        SZ  |  the number of elements T of [1, Z] such that
       *TsjT2     |   T * sum of digits of T in base 2
      q      Z    |   equals Z
  <1              |  is greater than 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
[x|x<-[1..],sum[1|n<-[1..x],n*h!!(n-1)==x]>1]
h=1:do x<-h;[x,x+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxDsIgFADQ3VO0iUOr0PTHzfZ7A2cHJIYUFFJAIjX5Q88umji@4VmVZ@N90XgtglYauYCukyy/g4A1/kmSxZ2t6yZyaBFJnkBuLMJRP6vfsIMgRnuQJSgXMah0vlXp5eKyXdRsLtZ504x46Pu@1eUz3b165MKnlL4)

The list defined in the first line is the infinite list of duplicates in the sequence. `h` is a helper infinite list that contains the hamming weight of \$n\$ at position \$n-1\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
≔⁰θＦＮ«≦⊕θＷ›²ＬΦθ⁼θ×λΣ⍘λ²≦⊕θ»Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3LCsIwFETX7Vfc5Q1EqN12paJSUBHqD8R6bQNJ2rx0IX57bNG1sxqGc5i2F64dhEpp5b3sDBYcLKvy@@AAazPGcIr6Sg4Zg1eeHcX442rTOtJkAt2@RvbspSLAvSMRJqHkcCDThR53Us2D5bC1USg/t4vU5FFxaKLGtfDUBCdNNy8l@wX@vL3z88QH3Agf0DJWpbQs0uKhPg) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th element of the sequence. Explanation:

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start the accumulator at `0`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Find `n` elements of the sequence.

```
≦⊕θ
```

Increment the accumulator.

```
Ｗ›²ＬΦθ⁼θ×λΣ⍘λ²
```

While the number of integers whose base 2 sum multiple equals the accumulator is less than 2, ...

```
≦⊕θ
```

... increment the accumulator.

```
»Ｉθ
```

Output the accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>140</s> 136 bytes

```
func[n][i: m: 1 until[d: 0 repeat k i: i + 1[p: k b: 0
until[b: p % 2 * k + b(p: p / 2)= 0]if b = i[d: d + 1]]if d > 1[m: m + 1]n < m]i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDsMgEEP3fIWXSm0zFDKiph@RFd0QCkinFoQQ@X56NNv52WfX4PsWvKUpmh6P/LaZLBskA40jN/5ab6BQQwl7wwfiMWZoW4woJ950xuQsuGDBXfgMdy0DPLDcVijiCIcVPNr8@KeBPF7SJFvpjzKeSMTUS@XcEKFV/wE)

Returns the \$n\$th element of the sequence.

Since the above code is really slow, I decided to write a faster function:

## Faster alternative, 168 bytes

```
func[n][r:[]m: copy#()i: 0 until[p: i: i + 1 b: 0
until[b: p % 2 * i + b(p: to 1 p / 2)= 0]either m/:b[r:
union r to[]b][m/:b: 1](length? r)=(2 * n)]take/part sort r n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX3/YoLIiS66ANXAfEf3IZZNG1qg20SYrrw6@NUwc1w58yZm@xY7nbUVE2qTJsftCedlKZVYQjxfRDSKTTYfHaLjgq8OZzRwjCufphjxBEdTt@bEezlwE5EjU5e0ZB1ebYJa60M1/OfCx6JLU2G9I4VWhKL9Y8835DkVex1XlLun7aOfcp4BR4JnkpMzmdMaLtL9c9N@QA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 66 bytes

```javascript
for(d=o=[];;o[d]&&print(d))o[p=(h=n=>n&&h(n&n-1)+d)(++d)]=o[p]+1|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxCsAgDADA34QEEepWkPQj4iCVoh0SseLUv9sut9ydZnrOXtuwc1/r0o6ZlUP0XkOOAK1XGZiJNDTGwsKHABQUEOvIZELzE/nvaNy7rfUB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
loop{p$.if(1..$.+=1).count{|y|y*y.digits(2).sum==$.}>1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pyc/v6C6QEUvM03DUE9PRU/b1lBTLzm/NK@kuqayplKrUi8lMz2zpFjDSFOvuDTX1lZFr9bOsPb/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>78</s> 76 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Kirill L.*

```r
repeat{T=T+1;s=0;for(n in 1:T)s=s+(n*sum(n%/%2^(0:n)%%2)==T);if(s>1)show(T)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr7iQtDoIjJD6is4mDhAZLIZqHIxvx7vWe0tn2q6XiScXlWzMtYEMRQYXGJV0Ahn1PkDMbPwKNgga45GIMZYMujjUvT7A@PX@Aw)

Comment: @KirillL. - Thanks!  Somehow I was sure I'd tried ```repeat``` + ```for```, or something similar, but obviously didn't get it right...

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>81</s> 78 bytes

```clj
#(for[i(range):when(second(for[j(range i):when(=(*(Long/bitCount j)j)i)]j))]i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lck7DsJADAXAnlNYovGjIbRIVLTcAKXIx5vYIBttNsrxFwS0M8MzbM1SeZREqe45Rb4r584nwXmbxXmRIXz8hv2C9F8XPvAtfDr2Wq6xeiGDQdEa0CoqdvzK@mEu3UPo1BAnAPUN)

Returns the infinite sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èò_*¤è1Ãè¥X z}jU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yPJfKqToMcPopVggen1qVQ&input=MTA)

Thanks to @Galen Ivanov for spotting an error which once fixed saved me 1 Byte!

```
È ... }jU  - first input U elements to return a truthy value when passed trough : f(XYZ)
ò_   >  range[0..X] trough f(Z)
*      * multiply Z by
¤è1Ã   * convert to binary string an count '1's
è¥X  > is number of elements == X
z    > divided by 2 not 0 ?
```

Comment: I think your solution doesn't list 6180 - can you check?

Comment: Yes @Galen Ivanov I thought I had to output only doubled while 6180 is triple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒLDb1ö*y¢2@
```

Outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5N8XJIMD2/Tqjy0yMjh/38A)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞            # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ           # Filter each value `y` by:
  L          #  Pop and create a list in the range [1,`y`]
   D         #  Duplicate this list
    b        #  Convert each inner value to a binary-String
     1ö      #  Sum the digits of each inner binary-String (by converting it to base-1)
       *     #  Multiply each binary-sum to its [1,`y`] value of the duplicated list
        y¢   #  Count how many times `y` occurs in this list
          2@ #  And check whether this count is larger than or equal to 2
             # (after which the filtered infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```